# A sequence converging to the number of decompositions of $2n$ as a sum of 2 primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For every even positive integer $n>2$ and every non-negative integer $k$, let's define the sequence $N_{k}(n)$ as follows:
$$N_{k}(n):=\displaystyle{\sum_{m=3}^{n/2}\frac{1}{\Omega(m)^k}\cdot\frac{1}{\Omega(n-m)^k}},$$ where $\Omega(m)$ is the total number of prime factors of $m$ counted with multiplicity. $\Omega(m)=1$ if and only if $m$ is prime, so that as $k$ increases, $N_{k}(n)$ decreases from $\frac{n}{2}-2$ to $G(n)$, where $G(n)$ is the number of couples $(p,q)$ such that $p\le q$, $p$ and $q$ are primes and $p+q=n$.

My question is: can an asymptotics for $N_{k}(x)$ be determined for large even $x$ and every $k$?
Thanks in advance.